# Hide overflow text in span using css

Tags: css

I want to display a long text inside fixed height & width of span element.

I have a text displaying current something like this inside span element

```
My Skill is
  Web 
Designing.
```

i have given him this CSS

```
span
{
    display:block;
    height:40px;
    width:90px;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

it give me result like this

```
My Skill is
  Web
```

but It is not my desired result. I want it to display something like this

```
My Skill is
  Web...
```

Is there any way to solve this problem..??
Thank you in advance..

Comment: try adding this property white-space: nowrap;

Comment: also, provide a fiddle next time..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the following property in span rule

```
white-space: nowrap;
```